# How can I insert multiple pictures in a beamer document so that they appear one after another like in a serial letter?

Tags: beamer

I want to create a serial document in latex like it can be done with MS Word. Apart from normal text data, I also want to include pictures serially. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can simply use a csv list and some of the common data processing packages for csv and create your serial document.

Answer (score 3):

When asking questions it is much better if you include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to explain fully what you want. Ideally you should post some close to working code, complete with the `\documentclass` command and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. This makes it easier for people to help you both because it makes it much clearer what you want and because there is some working code to start from.

I think that you just want to display a series of images on different beamer slides. If so then the following will do what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}% for some example images
\usepackage{pgffor}% loading \foreach
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Some pictures}
    \foreach \image [count=\fr] in {example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c} {
       \only<\fr> {This is image \image: \includegraphics[width=20mm]{\image}}
       \pause
     }
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have use the [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package for some sample images. The `\foreach` statement from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is used to loop over the images.

Here is the output:

[image]